# Detect safari and stop script

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a script which I need to deactivate for safari (desktop only) due to compatibility issues.

The script must be in the body and cant be in a linked .js file.

I have tried to add a if statement in order to amend "Cburl" of the script so if safari is detected and a bad url is given so the script will not load.

Original

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cbuser = { name: '', email: '', message: '' },
        access_token = '3354777755',
        cburl = '//www.domain.com/help/';
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + cburl + 'assets/help/js/script.js"></' + 'script>');
</script>
```

With safari detection:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent); //check if safari
    var cbuser = { name: '', email: '', message: '' },
        access_token = '3354777755',
    if(!safari){         
        cburl = '//www.domain.com/nohelp/';
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + cburl + 'assets/help/js/script.js"></' + 'script>');
    }
    else {
    cburl = '//www.domain.com/help/';
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + cburl + 'assets/help/js/script.js"></' + 'script>');
    }
</script>
```

Is there a fault with the way im detecting safari?

Comment: What "*compatibility issues*"? You'd be better testing for this instead.

Comment: Oh that is beyond me. To scripts dont work together due to the way that safari pre calculates the background size preload (I think). will gladly pay if anyway can fix this.

Comment: Then wouldn't you be better present this initial issue, as an other question, with a [MCVE]?

Comment: I didnt think it would be a permitted question. It would require looking into https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ working with http://chatbull.in/ on safari or a workaround on the way safari calculates (if that is the problem)

Comment: No it would require you to look there and to extract a Minimal Example that does Reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used to check if the user is using safari with this.

```
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Then you can stop the script doing this:

```
if(isSafari){ 
  alert('Is safari');
  //Do something

} else {
  alert('Is other browser');
  // Do something
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynrtffge/19/) so you can play with it.

Here is a snippet for your specific case. I changed the `document.write` to `windows.location` in order to make it work.

```js
var isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if(isSafari) { 
   var cbuser = { name: '', email: '', message: '' };
   var access_token = '7654345676';
   window.location = "https://www.example.com/notSafari";
} else {
  var cbuser = { name: '', email: '', message: '' };
  var access_token = 'Z2SxfM5dRzKsm3Auhbi4';
  window.location = 'https://www.example.com';
}
```

> Just change the ´https://www.example.com´ to your URLs.

Comment: I added more information for clarification purposes.

Comment: Thank you, i applied the code. have i done it correctly as no script is loaded. Thank you https://jsfiddle.net/6aL4pvqe/3/

Comment: Happy to help. Remember that you don't need the `<script></script>` when you are writing on a .js file.
Can you mark the answer as resolved? It might help other people.

Comment: Ok i will try that, Still not working, maybe the <script> is causing the issue. i will remove and report back

Comment: Also remember that you can't redirect to a `http` website from a `https`. You need to remember the _s_ from the fiddle url in order to test it propertly.
Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/6aL4pvqe/7/

Comment: I have updated to handle the https yet still doesnt appear on any browser. are the two if statement correct or have i missed something: https://jsfiddle.net/ynrtffge/1/

Comment: @thank_K please read the main answer. It's edited and working as you expect. It has also a example including your code working.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if browser is safari by matching `useragent` and initialize a variable. Using that variable, you can run code for other browsers.

```
var safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent); //check if safari

if(!safari){ 
    // do rest of operation
}
```

Comment: Still not working... with the new different detection added

Comment: Can you please explain what is not working? Is ```script.js``` loaded even after browser detection? Can you print in console ```navigator.userAgent``` and provide it here.

Comment: The script is not being loaded on any browser.I will print and post

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - This is tagged at "(!safari)"